# Solr Jira 1143 - Get Partial Results

Tags: solr, solrj

I realised I will have to apply the patch mentioned in Solr Jira [1143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1143) to return partial results when one of my shards is dead/slow. But the patch has no version explicitly specified. I am using Solr 3.5.0 and can I apply the patch to my installation as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an obsolete patch.

Use the features described in this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3134

That is in trunk.

If you add `&shards.tolerant=true` to the request, it will not abort on errors (timeout or other).